# Sublime text editor doesn't auto-refreshes the file if it is modified by another program

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, text-editor

Although Sublime is a really powerful text editor but I am facing an issue. I have been using sublime text editor to view logs of my application.Suppose I have already opened file in my editor. After the logs are modified by the app server. 
Sublime doesn't give any popup like we get in other editors

Example:

NOtepad++ says:

[image]

Also it doesn't modify the file. I have to close the file explicitly and then I re-open the file to ready the modified logs.

Only options i get in my sublime preferences are :

[image]

Please help..!

Comment: i have never faced this issue.Sublime is autoreloading modified files without asking

Comment: I didn't get any perfect solution but a down-vote ?

Comment: Sublime Text 1.4 is ancient. Version 2 and recently a beta version 3 is available https://www.sublimetext.com/3. Use version 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an extremely outdated version of sublime (1.4). You can enable this functionality by upgrading and performing a small settings tweak:

- Download the new [SublimeText](https://download.sublimetext.com/Sublime%20Text%20Build%203126%20Setup.exe)
- Install it and open it
- Go to the preferences menu and select "settings"

[image]

- This will open the settings files for sublime, scroll down to line 349 on the left panel and copy that line.
- Paste in the copied line into the right pane and replace "false" with "true"
  [image]
- Save and restart SublimeText

This should fix your issue entirely while also upgrading you to the awesome new SublimeText :)

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Set the following setting to true.

`Menu > Preferences > Settings`

```
// Always prompt before reloading a file, even if the file hasn't been
// modified. The default behavior is to automatically reload a file if it
// hasn't been edited. If a file has unsaved changes, a prompt will always
// be shown.
"always_prompt_for_file_reload": true
```

Comment: Sublime Text Version 1.4 is very old. There have been 2 major versions since that version. [Sublime Text Version 3](https://www.sublimetext.com/3) has the setting described above.